# How do I convert a flat list to a list of lists based on value of the elements in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list
`arr=[1,-1,4,-1,4,2]`

Is there a way to convert it to `[[1],[4],[4,2]]`?

Basically the -1 indicates where a sub-list ends

I tried

```
number_of_sublists=arr.count(-1)
lst=[[]]*(number_of_sublists+1)
    
idx=0
for i in arr:
    print(idx)
    if i==-1:
        idx+=1
    else:
        lst[idx].append(i)
print(lst)
```

but it is giving me the output

```
[[1,4,4,2],[1,4,4,2],[1,4,4,2]]
```

Why is this happening

Comment: What is the conversion is based of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr=[1,-1,4,-1,4,2]
newarr = [[]]
for i in arr:
    if i != -1:
        newarr[-1].append(i)
    else:
        newarr.append([])
print(newarr)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [4], [4, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertols.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

arr = [1, -1, 4, -1, 4, 2]

[[*g] for k, g in groupby(arr, key=(-1).__ne__) if k]
# [[1], [4], [4, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers provided work for your task, but if you want to know why your original code did not work, it is because how you are declaring the list `lst`.

```py
lst=[[]]*(number_of_sublists+1)
```

By doing this, you are repeating the same list at each of the positions of `lst`, that is, yo have made `number_of_sublists+1` references to the same list. So when you modify one of them, you are actually modifying all at the same time.

You could simply change the declaration to this and that would solve your problem:

```py
lst = [[] for _ in range(number_of_sublists+1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

try the below

```
arr = [1, -1, 4, -1, 4, 2]
result = [[]]
create_new_list = False
for x in arr:
    if x == -1:
        create_new_list = True
    else:
        if create_new_list:
            result.append([])
            create_new_list = False
        result[-1].append(x)
print(result)
```

output

```
[[1], [4], [4, 2]]
```